# How do I trigger an event on a higher-up element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm only a few hours new to React, so I might have missed something obvious. I have an app which looks a bit like this:

```
  var App = React.createClass({
    myAction: function(thingId) {
      this.setState({currentThing: thingId});
    },

    render: function() {
      return (<ThingsContainer app={this}/>);
    }
  });

  var ThingsContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (<ThingList app={this.props.app}/>);
    }
  });

  var ThingList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var self = this;
      var thingNodes = this.props.data.map(function (thing) {
        return (<Thing thing={thing} app={self.props.app} key={thing.id}></Thing>);
      });
      return (<div>{thingNodes}</div>);
    }
  });

  var Thing = React.createClass({
    performAction: function() {
      this.props.app.myAction(this.props.thing.id);
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.thing.title}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.performAction}>pip!</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I want to trigger an event on the top-level object from a lower-level object. The [relevant page](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) doesn't seem to address this situation directly.

In my solution I'm passing down the `app` object several levels. This doesn't feel right. In Ember I would be able to use a singleton Controller. In Angular I'd probably use a service. In Backbone or jQuery I'd use an event.

I don't know how much magic wiring of this sort to expect from React.

Is my above solution, which involves explicit wiring between components, even across several edges, the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass down the function instead of the whole object:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    myAction: function(thingId) {
      this.setState({currentThing: thingId});
    },

    render: function() {
      return (<ThingsContainer myAction={this.myAction}/>);
    }
  });

  var ThingsContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (<ThingList myAction={this.props.myAction}/>);
    }
  });

  var ThingList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var self = this;
      var thingNodes = this.props.data.map(function (thing) {
        return (<Thing thing={thing} myAction={this.props.myAction} key={thing.id}></Thing>);
      });
      return (<div>{thingNodes}</div>);
    }
  });

  var Thing = React.createClass({
    performAction: function() {
      this.props.myAction(this.props.thing.id);
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.thing.title}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.performAction}>pip!</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

other than that I don't see anything wrong with your approach, it does feel a bit strange at first but the nice thing about it is that the parent element is always responsible for directly modifying state, and it's very easy to debug issues like this since there is a very clear and concise 'flow'.